# Adding a HTML5 UI to an existing WCF/WIF/MVVM codebase

Tags: wcf, html, mvvm, wif

We have developed a SOA product which uses WCF and WIF with a custom Security Token Service servicing clients written using MVVM and WPF and even a Sharepoint integrated Silverlight solution.

A requirement has now been raised by one of our customers to produce a HTML5 web front end so they can access these resources via an iPad hosted web application.

This is obviously new territory for us and raises several questions we are struggling to answer via the web.

1. How much of WCF/WIF is supported by HTML5's Websockets?  e.g. `IssuedTokenWSTrustBinding` & `WS2007FederationHttpBinding`.
2. Do we need to rewrite huge swathes of our MVVM code, or it is possible to bind HTML5 to a C# `ViewModel`?

Any insight into any of these questions would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

1. Websockets are just... Websockets they don't do anything fancy beside data transport. So it will not handle anything as IssuedTokenWSTrustBinding  or WS2007FederationHttpBinding.
2. Normally a mobile application should differ from a full desktop browser application, there are things which must be taken into consideration such as: navigation, image sizes, amount of data used in the traffic. Every thing has to be kept at lowest rate as possible. If you don't mind ignoring all the above, then the answer is yes, you can add the required HTML5 functionality into your Views/ViewMOdels.

Comment: Thanks for your input but could you clarify some things? 
Are you saying websockets don't even support SSL or WS-* standards, that seems bizarre... also I appreciate your point about optimising a mobile site, but it's not entirely clear from your response if HTML5 has something similar to XAML Bindings, do you know if this is the case?  Thanks again

Comment: Websockets do support SSL (natively called WSS) but there is no support for any WS-* standards, and to be honest thats not their purpose. You can read more about websockets at: http://www.websocket.org/aboutwebsocket.html.

Comment: About HTML5 data bidding, there is nothing like that in it. You would have to use a third party javascript framework as knockout (http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/introduction.html).